# add two tags styles in style property of angular in angular component

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am new at angular 2.
 In this component, the style is working for h4 but not working for div "myClass" class.
Please look into it.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector : 'my-tutorials',
    template : `<h4>Hello World {{yaa}}</h4>
                <div [class.myClass] = "yo">NEC</div>`,
    styles :  [`h4 {
        color : red;      
    } , 
     .myClass{
        color :blue;
    }`]

})




export class TutorialsComponent{
    public yaa = "Mohith Hello";
    public yo = true;
}
```

Comment: The comma doesn't belong in the `styles`; you have a single string there, not multiple items.

Comment: As @jonrsharpe said, it's just invalid CSS

Comment: Oh!!!!!!! Thanks a lot..:)